# Create a Numpy Array from particular text format

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file containing the training vectors

```
<Vector 1-dimension 1>       <Vector 1 - dimension 2>   ....   <Vector 1 - dimension n>
.............  .............  .............  .............  .............  
<Vector m - dimension 1>     <Vector m - dimension 2>   ....   <Vector m - dimension n>
```

Another text file mentions the class memberships of the corresponding vectors

```
Vector1-Class
Vector2-Class
.............
Vector n - Class
```

Now, I need to convert these into numpy arrays X and Y, so that I can give them as input to Scikit Learn Linear SVM function ; for example as in this python code,

```
from sklearn import svm

X = [[1,1], [1,-1], [-1,1], [-1,-1]]
Y = [0, 1, 2, 3]
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I have used

```
X = np.genfromtxt("X.txt",delimiter=" ")
Y = np.genfromtxt("Y.txt",delimiter=" ")
```

to achieve the same.

Is there any better way to achieve the same? Also if my textfile is written in a sparse format, that is, if only nonzero elements are mentioned as ordered pairs, how can I achieve the same result?